# Customizing the Tensorflow Dataset's Type specification

Tags: python, tensorflow

## Background

I am trying to build a transformer model for text summarization. My dataset is the CNN daily mail and I used TF dataset series of APIs to retrieve them.

sample code:

```
    cnn_builder = tfds.summarization.cnn_dailymail.CnnDailymail()
    cnn_info = cnn_builder.info
    cnn_builder.download_and_prepare()
    datasets = cnn_builder.as_dataset()
    train_dataset, test_dataset = datasets["train"], datasets["test"]
```

## Problem

The type specification of the train_dataset is like this. As you can see, it is like a dict while I wanted to be like a tuple so that it is easier for me to tokenize each instance.

```
calling train_dataset.element_spec will return the element spec
{'article': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None),
 'highlights': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None)}
```

## Desired dataset type specification

```
(TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None))
```

## Experiments and Questions

I did not find such APIs to transform the elements of dataset into another form, also failed to retrieve each element and concatenate them. Anyone had any ideas? Or how can I iterate each instance in the dataset if using current form? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`tf.data.Dataset.map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) method to transform the dictionary into a tuple.

```py
dset = train_dataset.map(lambda d: (d['article'], d['highlights']))
```

To test this, you can grab the first item in each dataset and compare the dictionary and tuple versions.

```py
out_orig = next(iter(train_dataset))
out_mapped = next(iter(dset))
tf.assert_equal(out_orig['article'], out_mapped[0])
tf.assert_equal(out_orig['highlights'], out_mapped[1])
```

Here is the element spec:

```
>>> dset.element_spec
(TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None))
```